# Python program to read symbols

Tags: python, camera

Looking to have python take input from a camera and have it read what it sees. 
For example the camera lens sees ...---... and would translate that to SOS.
Trying to find a good pattern to use that would go back to a database and tell the program a location. But I'm first trying to figure out how I could take a camera lens and it would see the pattern and feed what it sees to a program to determine location.

I found this article: [count colored dots in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439555/count-colored-dots-in-image)

But it was reading and counting color dots. So similar, but I want to be able to recognize a pattern (bar code, Morse code, ect) and related it back to a location (thinking I will have this in a database of some sort).

Thanks for any input or direction you can give.

Comment: Can python read a video feed (real time) from the camera or would it be better to have the camera take a picture and then have the program read the image and find the symbol?

Comment: look for shape detection (ex : http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/) or if if your image look like a tape, you can binarize it , then read it (left to right) and with threshold and buffers find if it's `.` or `-`...

Comment: Thanks that might be more on track. I also came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46081382/python-program-to-read-symbols and http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/24/detecting-barcodes-images-python-opencv/    Think I like the symbol as that would probably be easier to produce my own meanings from.

Comment: What would be a good resource to look at where python could use some logic to figure out its location? For example say the camera sees an image that puts it between four different symbols. Could the program figure out its position? Or if it sees parts of four different symbols each with some unique (but not all of the symbol) could it id its location?

Comment: you ca read trought your image and use machine learning to make classification (have a look about scikit-learn)