# How to count number of dots in an image using python and Opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to count number of dots in an image.
The image looks like
[image: Dots Image]

I referred to this SOF link [count colored dots in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439555/count-colored-dots-in-image)
But this is for colored links , So anyone here can guide me over how to handle this and count black dots out of white back.

Comment: I refer you to the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44478021/6437980) to the question you've posted. Hough transform works in binary images.

Comment: To get you started, there is a Matlab tutorial one a similar topic. Just look up what the functions used there do and find their equivalent in OpenCV, Pillow, ect.
https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/image-enhancement-and-analysis.html

Comment: Are you interested in 3rd party libary functions or a fundamental code/approach itself?

Comment: 3rd party code library funtions

Comment: If the image is always like that and you want a short fast answer I would say use `connectedComponents` from OpenCV it may deal with points that are bigger, and will return the number of labels (background counts as a label). The only thing is that black is background for this function as far as I remember.... so you have to do invert the image first... bitwise_not should do the trick quite fast. Also make sure it is a binary image (CV_8U in OpenCV with 0 for black and 255 for white)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `thredhold` using `THRESH_BINARY_INV` flag, change to black-background-white-foreground.
2. `findContours`, filter the contours by area(calculated by `contourArea`)
3. You get it

---

```
import cv2
gray = cv2.imread("dots.jpg", 0)

## threshold
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

## findcontours
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]


## filter by area
s1= 3
s2 = 20
xcnts = []
for cnt in cnts:
    if s1<cv2.contourArea(cnt) <s2:
        xcnts.append(cnt)

print("Dots number: {}".format(len(xcnts)))
#Dots number: 23
```

---

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The answer you point to converts the coloured image to grayscale, therefore you should apply [`HoughCircles()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d) to your image and find out the length of result array.