# detecting dots in image- opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image from a Petri dish that I want to detect black round dots (number and location), preferably in python+opencv.
I tried different methods in python opencv, but no success, e.g. hough circle, findContours, etc.

I used [How to count number of dots in an image using python and Opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154642/how-to-count-number-of-dots-in-an-image-using-python-and-opencv) and [count colored dots in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439555/count-colored-dots-in-image/44443494). The problem for both methods is that they also detect the right section also as dots (outside from the dish). Therefore the number of detected dots are very high~2K
[image]
[image: input]

desired output:
[image: desired output]

Comment: Your initial image was binary or colored? If coloured, please share that also. And, also mention in detail what approaches did you use and what was their outputs.

Comment: provide your raw input image, not a binary image that is most likely already sub-optimal. that you try to use hough circles here shows that you have no idea what you're doing. so you probably lost a lot of useful data in your initial steps

Comment: @RahulKedia I uploaded the original images.
As mentioned I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154642/how-to-count-number-of-dots-in-an-image-using-python-and-opencv and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439555/count-colored-dots-in-image/44443494
The problem for both method is that It also detects the right section also as dots (outside from the dish). Therefore the number of detected dots are very high~2K

Comment: your image is not very good. start with a good image not some random snapshot. get proper lighting, adjsutment, background,  focus... I suggest you read a book on applied image-processing. I consider processing such an image a waste of time

Comment: @Piglet Dear Piglet, Thanks for your comments. I only have this quality for my images. You say that I cannot do anything with this?

Comment: you can but it means a lot of unnecessary head-ache, work and sub-optimal results. crap in == crap out.  having repeatable lighting and conditions is cruicial for a solution. if you say you only have images like that I assume you only have freehand snapshots. so any solution that will work for this example will most like not work for any other image. that's why you usually invest most of the time and money into getting proper images.

Comment: @Piglet Can you please suggest any solution which works for this image? I can apply your solution to others and return you with the generalization power.

Comment: It all depends on what you want out of it.Is it a standardized way of counting you will rutinely implement or is it some other smaller and focused task

Comment: Also for image processing takeing a full image of the dish might be nice, and using a dish that is not gridded.

Comment: You could edit the original image to remove the cloth that the petri dish is sitting on. That would remove all of the false positives in that area.

Comment: @Karson Can you please elaborate this in more detail? maybe a code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Simple Blob Detector technique which is used for Detecting the round objects on image. There are many parameters which also helps you like defining the minsize of Blob(objects),filterBy Inertia,filterBy Convexity, and Filter by Color. For reference you can access the docs link(https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html)